# Why do zerglings with speed beat normal zerglings?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

With Metabolic boost "speedlings" become a lot better then the un-upgraded zergling. This is because they are faster. But when matched up with even number of un-upgraded zerglings they always win. If the metabolic boost upgrade only increases speed, why does it seem to increase rate of attack and DPS?

Comment: It *does* increase DPS because there is less "dead time" when they're moving instead of attacking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The speed upgrade allows the zerglings to do what they do best - surround - faster.

The more zerglings hitting your zerglings, the quicker they die, and the faster zerglings can surround other zerglings, the more zerglings are hitting your zerglings.

Comment: zerglings zerglings zerglings

Comment: .....zerglings?

Answer (score 0):

If you have lings with no speed and are facing speedlings, then make sure to get in a group and not a line. This will diminish the value of the speed boost because it will limit the effectiveness of the speedlings to get a surround on individual lings.

In general, the reason the speed boost wins is because your slow lings are traveling in a line, and are susceptible to being surrounded and owned.

To put it this way, the winner of 1 speed ling versus 1 normal ling will be determined by who strikes first (assuming no armor or weapons bonus). The winner of 6 speed lings versus 6 normal lings will be determined by how many micro battles have better odds for the speed lings. For example, if it can be 4 speed lings versus 1 ling, and then 2 versus 1, while the other 4 slow lings are still trying to get in combat, the odds are very high that the speedlings will win.